# GAMM: Removing an interaction changes variance confidence interval of other terms

Tags: variance, interaction, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, gratia

I'm learning how to interpret the output of the `gratia::variance_comp` function. I noticed that removing an interaction changed the confidence intervals of a variance estimate drastically. I removed the `by=` term from model 1, because `k.check(m1)` showed problems, increasing k wasn't helping, the plot wasn't smooth, and so it seemed like I didn't have enough data for this term. I'm hoping to understand why removing it changed the variance interval so much (and if that's a problem), but also to check my understanding of what the results tell me. Does it have anything to do with the warnings?

The full dataset is too large (n=1327), so here's a small subset for reference. It doesn't reproduce the "effect" though.

```
> MyVar <- c("num", "sal")
> df <- shrimp2[MyVar][sample(nrow(shrimp2[MyVar]), 100), ]

> dput(df)
structure(list(num = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), sal = c(25.22, 7.7, 
25.67, 2.89, 27.72, 28.3, 23.56, 30.94, 23.64, 18.19, 22.79, 
7.69, 30.59, 36.53, 36.74, 11.66, 22.52, 3.34, 22.89, 11.29, 
2.26, 31.08, 31.3, 38.67, 20.25, 30.29, 24.19, 34.59, 22.83, 
32.35, 29.56, 31.97, 30.88, 29.46, 22.04, 22.08, 20, 25.65, 21.3, 
21.52, 30.72, 17.48, 10.03, 19.41, 26.26, 28.77, 19.35, 30.95, 
23.61, 22.56, 31.21, 22.37, 25.23, 25.5, 30.78, 6.99, 25.46, 
22.33, 6.25, 21.99, 26.98, 8.97, 33.79, 11.06, 21.89, 32.02, 
21.78, 0.5, 25.71, 17.55, 32.21, 33.44, 27.25, 32.93, 20.25, 
25.97, 26.81, 11.26, 13.57, 8.87, 19.93, 28.2, 27.97, 20.16, 
26.02, 32.71, 28.09, 33.52, 27.32, 25.63, 19.82, 23.11, 38.57, 
25.1, 26.49, 27.91, 20.7, 29, 13.21, 22.08)), row.names = c(131616L, 
280656L, 344136L, 312856L, 234656L, 203008L, 105856L, 243672L, 
264096L, 107512L, 106592L, 189760L, 322240L, 160872L, 397680L, 
268328L, 389032L, 313224L, 68504L, 275504L, 313408L, 97760L, 
198960L, 227664L, 338064L, 398600L, 117632L, 246248L, 207976L, 
398784L, 164184L, 199696L, 303656L, 325368L, 285256L, 117080L, 
373760L, 331624L, 286176L, 214600L, 110640L, 220304L, 276608L, 
86168L, 237600L, 229136L, 251400L, 401176L, 252320L, 252688L, 
244776L, 391240L, 320768L, 176880L, 319296L, 213312L, 173752L, 
68688L, 212208L, 202272L, 118368L, 346712L, 138792L, 265568L, 
115056L, 199512L, 352416L, 277528L, 331992L, 298688L, 130144L, 
112112L, 187000L, 236496L, 390320L, 388480L, 119656L, 266304L, 
222328L, 269248L, 186264L, 400256L, 201352L, 298872L, 332544L, 
199328L, 234104L, 166576L, 142840L, 141184L, 286544L, 239992L, 
164736L, 347448L, 122232L, 234472L, 249744L, 162896L, 269800L, 
65744L), class = "data.frame")


df$year <- rep(2011:2020, each=10)
df$CYR.std <- df$year - min(df$year)
df$fCYR <- as.factor(df$year)

df$fSite <- seq(1, 5, 1)
df$fSite <- as.factor(df$fSite)

df$fSeason <- rep(c("DRY", "WET"), each=5)
df$fSeason <- as.factor(df$fSeason)

df$area_sampled <- 3
```

Response plot from full dataset ("num" variable = abundance data):

```
plot(table(shrimp2$num), 
     type = "h",
     cex.lab = 1.5,
     ylab = "Frequencies",
     xlab = "counts")
```

[image]

```
with(shrimp2, nlevels(interaction(fCYR, fSite, drop = TRUE)))
[1] 705

m1 <- bam(num ~ s(sal) + 
            
            s(CYR.std, by = fSeason, m=1) + 
            
            fSeason +
            
            s(fCYR, bs = "re") + 
            s(CYR.std, fSite, bs = "fs"), 
          offset(log(area_sampled)),
          method = "fREML",
          discrete = TRUE,
          family = nb(link = "log"),
          data = shrimp2)

m2 <- bam(num ~ s(sal) + 
            
            s(CYR.std) +
            # s(CYR.std, by = fSeason, m=1) + 
            
            fSeason +
            
            s(fCYR, bs = "re") + 
            s(CYR.std, fSite, bs = "fs"), 
          offset(log(area_sampled)),
          method = "fREML",
          discrete = TRUE,
          family = nb(link = "log"),
          data = shrimp2)
    
    Warning message:
    In gam.side(sm, X, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5) :
      model has repeated 1-d smooths of same variable.
```

Plot:

```
draw(m1)
```

[image]

Variance check:

```
> gratia::variance_comp(m1)
# A tibble: 7 × 5
  component             variance std_dev lower_ci upper_ci
  <chr>                    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 s(sal)                0.000216  0.0147  0.00832   0.0260
2 s(CYR.std):fSeasonDRY 0.367     0.606   0.336     1.09  
3 s(CYR.std):fSeasonWET 0.941     0.970   0.360     2.61  
4 s(fCYR)               0.0347    0.186   0.0700    0.496 
5 s(CYR.std,fSite)1     0.00278   0.0527  0.0384    0.0724
6 s(CYR.std,fSite)2     0.171     0.414   0.0137   12.5   
7 s(CYR.std,fSite)3     0.00471   0.0686  0.0388    0.121 

Warning messages:
1: In lsd - crit * sd.lsd :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In lsd + crit * sd.lsd :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

> gratia::variance_comp(m2)
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  component            variance  std_dev  lower_ci  upper_ci
  <chr>                   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 s(sal)            0.000146    0.0121   5.25e-  3 2.78e-  2
2 s(CYR.std)        0.0713      0.267    1.33e-  1 5.37e-  1
3 s(fCYR)           0.0705      0.265    8.47e-  2 8.32e-  1
4 s(CYR.std,fSite)1 0.00257     0.0507   8.13e-155 3.16e+151 # <- What happened here?
5 s(CYR.std,fSite)2 0.000000891 0.000944 6.79e-  4 1.31e-  3
6 s(CYR.std,fSite)3 0.165       0.407    1.77e-  1 9.36e-  1

Warning messages:
1: In lsd - crit * sd.lsd :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In lsd + crit * sd.lsd :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

> k.check(m1)
                        k       edf   k-index p-value
s(sal)                  9  2.785760 0.8585962  0.2475
s(CYR.std):fSeasonDRY   8  6.551136 0.8022335  0.0025
s(CYR.std):fSeasonWET   8  7.320707 0.8022335  0.0000
s(fCYR)                15  3.890708        NA      NA
s(CYR.std,fSite)      470 44.844182 0.8022335  0.0000

> k.check(m2)
                       k       edf   k-index p-value
    s(sal)             9  2.503754 0.8411143  0.1525
    s(CYR.std)         9  4.635525 0.7360063  0.0000
    s(fCYR)           15  6.435661        NA      NA
    s(CYR.std,fSite) 470 39.421491 0.7360063  0.0000
```

Comment: You might want to investigate those warning messages before proceeding.

Comment: I've read the first one (..."model has repeated 1-d smooths of same variable") can be ignored b/c I'm using s(CYR.std) twice, but for different purposes (one is random smooth and the other a fixed effect). Couldn't find anything yet on the "longer object length" warning in reference to gratia::variance_comp or modeling in general..

Comment: The confidence intervals seems entirely implausible so there must be something wrong here. Why does entering the term in more than once not matter here?

Comment: For sure, but I've seen crazy C.I. like this before without this warning message, so it's unclear to me how they're related - still working on it. It could be because I only have 1 observation for some sites in a single year. Entering a term more than once: my understanding is that s(CYR.std, fSite, bs = "fs") is the random slope term (annual site-specific deviations from the average year effect, s(fCYR, bs = "re")), while s(CYR.std) is the "global" year effect over-all sites.

Comment: As I wrote in the other place [so] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77898595/429846) the warning is a bug (IMHO) in `mgcv::gam.vcomp()` but which is highlighted by models that are not well-fitted to the data or are too complex or just otherwise degenerate in fit. Anytime you see uncertainty estimates like this that cover the possible range the parameter could take it should set alarm bells ringing that something is wrong with the model, data, both, or just the fit should be viewed with extreme care. And usually it's because I was asking too much from the data.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, got it thanks again!